# How to hide the pages while continue installation in NSIS script

Tags: nsis

I have working installer for my application in NSIS. It has several pages like license, directory, installfiles and finish.
Now what I wanted to do is, hide all the pages but continue the installation based on some condition.
I tried using Abort/MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE but it terminated the further installation.
Any pointers here?

Comment: Did you abort on the instfiles page?

Comment: @Anders: I did abort in the PRE function for license page.

Comment: @Anders: I tried using Abort in MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW, installation was correct but still pages were shown. Is there any other way to hide the pages while continuing the installation?

Answer (score 1):

You have to skip pages in the pre callback:

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE maybeskippages
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE maybeskippages
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Var SkipPages
Function .onInit
${GetParameters} $0
${GetOptions} "$0" "/Skip"  $1
${IfNot} ${Errors}
    StrCpy $SkipPages 1
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function maybeskippages
${If} $SkipPages > 0 
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: As you suggested, I Aborted in PRE callbacks, it skipped the pages, but installation didn't happen. Basically what I want is installation should be silent..

Comment: What does "installation didn't happen" mean? Are you using Section /o or do you have some other logic that unchecks sections? Try adding a section with just a MessageBox in it...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SetSilent silent` within `.onInit` function to hide the UI. Or you could use `MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE` hook function and with ShowWindow also.

Comment: Could you please give sample example, I didn't get your anwser.

Comment: I tried using SetSilent, didn't work. I also tried MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW and MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE  along with Abort but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use Abort in your MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW to skip this page.

Maybe you could try NSIS forums, there is plenty of similar questions and you get quickier answers.

Comment: I tried using Abort in MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW, but still pages were shown.
Is there any other way to hide the pages while continuing the installation?

Comment: Here is the code I tried:
 !define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW NoWizardFunc_SHOW
 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE $(MUILicense)
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW NoWizardFunc_SHOW
 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

Function NoWizardFunc_SHOW
MessageBox MB_OK "$NOWIZARD"

${IF} $NOWIZARD == 1
         Abort
${ENDIF}